# How to make smoke made in the smoke simulator transparent?

Tags: transparency, smoke-simulation

I am using the Physics Smoke Simulator to make a flame, the problem is  that with the flame comes smoke which I don't want. I tried setting the flow type of the emitter to Flame only, but their is still smoke. 
How do I remove this smoke or hide it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon I posted this question  I saw where I went wrong.

[image]

There is an option in the domain of the simulation called smoke which surprisingly adjusts the amount of smoke produced.